# Unable to view all css and javascript files which i have included

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

This is my **DefaultController.php**  I am unable to view my all css and js file which i have included it. i thing error will be in my internal css which i have mentioned in our twig file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Dl3.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO7gC.jpg)

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use AppBundle\Entity\Login;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
     * @Route("/timeline", name="timeline")
     */
    public function timelineAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/timeline.html.twig');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('timeline');
    }
}
```

This is my **timeline.html.twig** file, i don't know how to use internal css in twig

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}


    {% block stylesheets %}

    <style>

        div {
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

    </style>

    {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}  




         <hr />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 id="timeline">User Events</h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li>
                    <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">User Logged in</h4>                            
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 1 hour 20 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                               incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                               quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">User Content Search</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 57 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                               incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                               quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="timeline-badge danger"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Items added to shopping cart</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 37 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                               incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                               quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                   <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Payment processed</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 27 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                               incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                               quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">User logged out</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 10 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                               incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                               quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: first of all, you have a problem in your controller, you have two return

Comment: I can redirect same page in symfony,how

Comment: ok sir, sir but i am unable to view Unable to view all css and javascript files which i have included.

Comment: don't see any javascript in your post

Comment: When i removed {% block stylesheets %}...{% endblock %} i file browse properly can you explain how it can possible.

Comment: and if you put it, what do you have ?

Comment: i have used {% extends "::base.html.twig" %} in this file i have included my all css and js files

Comment: if you don't put all your code, we can't help you

Comment: sir i have edit my question and attached without using {% block stylesheets %}...{% endblock %} in my twig( before.jpg) and with using {% block stylesheets %}...{% endblock %} (after.jpg)

Comment: Put only necessary code! `Lorem ipsum` doesn't change anything, so remove it. Consider reading [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your base.html.twig but you probably have something like

```
...
{% block stylesheets %}
<link type="text/css" href="mycss1.css">
<link type="text/css" href="mycss2.css">
{% endblock %}
...
```

so in your timeline.html.twig you have to add `{{ parent() }}` at the beginning of the stylesheets block, in your case

```
{% block stylesheets %}

{{ parent() }}

<style>

    div {
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }

</style>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, sir can you explain and describe {{ parent() }} and its functionality.

Comment: this is inheritance, when you extends your layouts, you put your contents in the blocks but if you omit the parent() directive you completly override the block. when you add parent(), the original block is also included and your new content is appended to the block